# Is it okay to use ROS Navigation Stack for a heavy(200kg +) robot?

Tags: localization, navigation, ros-melodic, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I wanted to know if we can use the amcl, move_base along with existing planners like TEB and cost maps plugins for a robot weighing 200+ kgs? I intend to operate the robot at an average velocity of 0.7 m/s. I am more concerned about path tracking rather than localization.
Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401974/is-it-okay-to-use-ros-navigation-stack-for-a-heavy(200kg-+)-robot?/) by [rajs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84852/rajs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming the robot hardware is mechanically strong enough to control it, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use the navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [Alex-SSoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/86099/alex-ssom/) with karma: 163 on 2022-06-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is the software part of the robot and it's the logic that commands how the robot behaves to diverse scenarios, I think the weight here is linked directly to the motors' torque and the motor controller most be powerful enough to drive the motor and for the sake of completeness with a strong rigid chassis and wheels you will be good to go.

---

Originally posted by [offgrid8](https://answers.ros.org/users/89365/offgrid8/) with karma: 13 on 2022-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1